# Pass Through Query Generates "Invalid Cursor State" Error When Computer Upgraded To Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, windows-10, pass-through

Users in my office who have been upgraded to Windows 10 (build 1909) are suddenly getting the message "[Microsoft][ODBC Drive Manager] Invalid cursor state (#0)" whenever they run a pass through query in Microsoft Access. It doesn't matter how complicated the Pass Through query is, they all crash. We use SQL Server on our back-end. I have tried updating the ODBC drivers on our users' machines to the most recent version, but this doesn't solve the problem.

It is very frustrating because I can open tables linked to our SQL Server with no problem. I can write an equivalent query in Access and it will run. I even installed SQL Management Studio on one user's machine, and I could run the query fine there, I just cannot get the Pass Through to run. We are using 32 bit Access from Office 365 with the most recent updates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do all users have the same version of Access ?

Comment: It's an Office bug, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/odbc-call-failed-microsoftodbc-driver-manager/de303266-7e6a-45a8-ac61-1164bec89e98

Comment: If you don't want such happenings and surprises, don't run the Insiders Release. As the name implies, it is intended for developers and first-movers who are prepared for this and that. Don't run it at normal users.

Comment: Thanks but I read that before I posted here. We have version 1902. We don't have the Insider's Release.

Comment: Win 10  (build 1909)  is beta too ! Missimg Sql-Server and ODBC Driver Version! ODBC trace log? Upgraded from Win7? Test new Drivers there too.